# Could not install SAP HANA Development tools in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: hana

I am trying to install SAP HANA development tools plug in from https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/neon url in Eclipse Oxygen Version.

But I am not able to install all the features. Encountering problem as with Install Remediation Dialog box and displaying the the some features list with caption as will not be installed.

Expecting all the 7 features to get installed but only Designer for SAP Cloud platform is getting installed.

Please help me out with the solution.

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoD8k.png)

Thanks,
Sneha.

Answer (score 0):

You said you're using the Neon-Repository with Eclipse Oxygen. Try the Repository for Oxygen and see if that works:
https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/oxygen/